# Error getting the Android ID in NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I wrote a method that gets the android ID in NDK

```
void getAndroidID(JNIEnv *env, jobject context, char *deviceId){

    int android_id_len = 16;

    //Get the Setting.Secure class and the Context Class
    jclass c_settings_secure = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/provider/Settings$Secure");
    jclass c_context = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/content/Context");
    if(c_settings_secure == NULL || c_context == NULL){
        return;
    }
    //Get the getContentResolver method
    jmethodID m_get_content_resolver = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c_context, "getContentResolver",
                                                           "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
    if(m_get_content_resolver == NULL){
        return;
    }

    //Get the Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID constant
    jfieldID f_android_id = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, c_settings_secure, "ANDROID_ID", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    if(f_android_id == NULL){
        return;
    }
    jstring s_android_id = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, c_settings_secure, f_android_id);

    //create a ContentResolver instance context.getContentResolver()
    jobject o_content_resolver = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, m_get_content_resolver);
    if(o_content_resolver == NULL || s_android_id == NULL){
        return;
    }

    //get the method getString
    jmethodID m_get_string = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, c_settings_secure, "getString",
                                                       "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    if(m_get_string == NULL){
        return;
    }

    //get the Android ID
    jstring android_id = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, c_settings_secure,
                                                        m_get_string,
                                                        o_content_resolver,
                                                        s_android_id);
    (*env)->GetStringUTFRegion(env, android_id, 0, android_id_len, deviceId);
    deviceId[android_id_len] = '\0';
    LOGI("deviceId %s", deviceId);
}
```

I tested this code in several phones and it works in all of them with the exception on one phone where I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; regionStart=0; regionLength=16`when I invoke the `GetStringUTFRegion` method.

Why I am getting the exception and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking to translate more characters than there are in the string - `android_id_len` has a hard-coded value of 16, whereas the string in this case is 15, as the error message says. Make sure you calculate the correct length of the string and pass that length to `GetStringUTFRegion`, and this way you code will be cross-device generic.

Comment: thanks, the problem was that the Android ID in that device was 15 characters long in hex form and I was always expecting a length of 16 (64 bits), I change my code and I am using  the function `GetStringUTFLength` first to get the actual length of the string.